# Use htaccess to alias to different hosting

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, cname-record, alias

I have a host `my.site.com` that doesn't support a PHP version that I need, so I got some new hosting at `newsite.com` that has a more up to date PHP version. I'm going host the site completely on `newsite.com`, but I want people to type in `my.site.com` to get there and see `my.site.com` in the address bar throughout their time using the site.

What is the best way to approach this through using an `htaccess` on `my.site.com`?

Comment: Why don't you just move my.site.com over to the new host?

Comment: It is hosted by a university. So more specifically, `my.site.com` is `mySpecificSubdomain.university.edu`.

Comment: IMHO you're better off for people to get used to new site.com, as your university sub domain is likely to expire when either you graduate or your research grant runs out, where typically your own domain and associated email addresses can be used through changes of university, employer and ISP.

Comment: It's actually an organization's website that will be passed down as the years go on.

Comment: No possibility to have the DNS record changed to  CNAME record pointing to newsite.com and your provider configuring my.site.con as a valid alias?

Comment: Would the university have to do this for me? Is this not something an htaccess could handle?

Answer (score 0):

Th classical way of doing what you ask for is using either HTML or programmatically include those parts of your remote site into a page/script on my.site.com.

Think of  an index.html on my.site.com that is nothing more than a (i)frame around newsite.oom.

Alternatively if you only need the remote PHP version for one or two functions use the php URL include.